# Bennet,Sharpley,Interpolation of Operators - Chapter $1$ notations

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, notation, normed-spaces

These photos are from Bennet,Sharpley,Interpolation of Operators book.
These are the definitions which may help you.
[image]
[image]
[image]

There is the photo of my question:
[image]
I don't understand the meaning of this red marked notation.

I would be grateful for any kind of  explanation.

Comment: What is a norm function? What is $\mathscr{M}_0$? I suggest you add the necessary definitions to know what you are talking about, or at least to understand th problem.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I've edited it.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Is right. We still don’t know what $M_0$ is. In general $\hookrightarrow$ denotes an inclusion map, eg the identity function from a subset to a superset

Comment: @FShrike check it now

Comment: Does my comment make sense to you? The hook arrow is an inclusions of subobjects (subsets, subspaces, …) so presumably $X\subseteq M_0¥

Comment: @JohnNash: now I see what you mean. In general, if $A\subset X$, the identity map $\iota: A\rightarrow X$ given by $x\mapsto x$, is denoted as $\iota:A\hookrightarrow X$. The result in your OP tells you among other things, how to construct integration theory from a "norm" function. That is the way Daniell and Stone construct Lebesgue integration.